# Manipulating "sticky bit" within a C program

Tags: c, linux

How do we set, reset and check the "sticky bit" from within a C program?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To read the stick bit you use `stat()` check the `.st_mode` for `S_ISVTX`

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

struct stat file_stats;
stat("my_file", &file_stats);
if (file_stats.st_mode & S_ISVTX)
    printf("sticky\n");
```

to reset it, you do it via `chmod`

```
struct stat file_stats;
stat("my_file", &file_stats);
mode_t new_mode = file_stats.st_mode & ~S_ISVTX;
chmod("my_file", new_mode);
```

to set it, `chmod` it is

```
struct stat file_stats;
stat("my_file", &file_stats);
mode_t new_mode = file_stats.st_mode | S_ISVTX;
chmod("my_file", new_mode);
```

this code is untested.

man pages: [stat(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) [chmod(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chmod)

Comment: Strictly speaking, this also tries to set the "file type" bits using `chmod`, which I believe is not allowed...  Also note that this code is racy; e.g. if your file gets deleted and replaced between the call to `stat()` and the call to `chmod()`.  (One reason `fstat` and `fchmod` are probably better; the other being performance...)

Comment: Are you sure chmod tries to set the "file type" bits, whatever they are? Also, if you are checking for the file being deleted between the calls you should also check for nuclear meltdown between the calls.

Comment: The `st_mode` field of `struct stat` includes the "file type" bits (regular file vs. directory vs. socket etc) in addition to the permissions.  And you cannot set those with `chmod`, so it is possible to get an error if you try.  And if you do not think it is worth worrying about race conditions involving file creation/deletion on Unix, I have some CERT advisories to show you...

Comment: I am reading the bits first, if you didn't pay attention. So I am guessing that if it is a dir, the "file type" bits obviously won't be set, unless the OS is trying to put a prank on me. And obviously, this is NOT production code, he HAS to check chmod's return value, since the most obvious error is that he doesn't have permission to be changing the file's permissions. He should also add the following function: int is_computer_powered_on() { return 1; }, just to be sure the computer is on between stat() and chmod().

Comment: Right, but even if it is a regular file, there will be a bit set to represent that...  And that bit is _not_ a legal bit to pass as part of the mask to `chmod`, period.  It may work on some systems, but if you read the POSIX spec, it is pretty clear that you are only supposed to pass actual permission bits to `chmod`.  In other words, I believe you need to properly mask out the non-permission bits from `st_mode` before passing it to `chmod`.

Comment: You are probably right. Feel free to write a better answer than my own, anytime. I will even upvote it

Comment: Nah, your answer is pretty good (and I have upvoted it).  I am just feeling obsessive-compulsive tonight; letting it out in these comments is enough :-)

Comment: If I hadn't drank the beers I drank, I would probably not even have answered this question, or your comments. :D

Comment: Thanks everyone...@Nemo :-) for being your obsessive-compulsive self @hexa thanks to the beers or rather TGIF

Answer (score 2):

It's bit 01000 (octal), so you can set it with `chmod(dir, 01000 | perms)`. I'm sure if you poke around the headers, maybe stat.h, you'll find the correct name for the bit.

Comment: Have a look at stat (2) - for example http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat the name is `S_ISVTX`

Comment: @mru: Indeed, and it is also part of the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html).

Comment: @jcomeau: Questioner also asked how to "check" the bit, so you might want to mention `stat` or `fstat`, also.

Comment: understood, but I was just getting ready to eat, and answered what I could off the top of my head (plus a little quick googling). figured others could fill in the remainder.